# Why is str(super(B, b)) not equivalent to super(B, b).__str__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

- Assume `A` is the parent class of `B` and `b` is an instance of `B`. Then an overriden method of `A` can be called with [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super): `super(B, b).method()`.
- The docs state ["`str(object)` returns `object.__str__()`"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) in its basic invocation.

It should follow that `str(super(B, b)) == super(B, b).__str__()`, but that's not the case ([interactive version](https://repl.it/NIfH/2)):

```
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return "A"


class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return "B"


b = B()   
b_super = super(B, b) 
print(str(b_super))       # "<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>"
print(b_super.__str__())  # "A"
```

So where did I go wrong? Does the super mechanism not work for magic methods? Does `str` not invoke `__str__` in this case? Is it related to this paragraph:

> Note that `super()` is implemented as part of the binding process for explicit dotted attribute lookups such as `super().__getitem__(name)`. It does so by implementing its own `__getattribute__()` method for searching classes in a predictable order that supports cooperative multiple inheritance. Accordingly, `super()` is undefined for implicit lookups using statements or operators such as `super()[name]`.

Comment: I believe it's because the `super` call returns `a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type`, which has its own `__str__`, not resolving to the 'A'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`str()` doesn't look up the `__str__` method through the normal attribute lookup procedure. Instead, it performs a direct search for the `__str__` method in the `__dict__`s of its argument's class hierarchy, in [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) order. This finds `super.__str__`, which gives `"<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>"`.

However, when you look up `b_super.__str__` manually, that goes through `super.__getattribute__`, the hook `super` uses to provide its special attribute lookup behavior. The lookup through `__getattribute__` will resolve to `A.__str__` and call that.

Consider this class, which illustrates the difference (I hope):

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other = other
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'other':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'other')
        elif name == '__str__':
            return getattr(self.other, name)
        else:
            return name
    def __str__(self):
        return 'fun'

>>> str(B(1))   # calls B.__str__ because it doesn't invoke __getattribute__
'fun'
>>> B(1).__str__()  # calls B.__getattribute__ to look up the __str__ method which returns (1).__str__
'1'
```

The problem in this case and likewise for `super` is that these are proxies that rely on `__getattribute__` to forward it. So any function or method that doesn't go through `__getattribute__` doesn't forward. And `str()` is such a function.

---

Just for completeness because it was mentioned in the comments and the other answer.

**But `str(x)` isn't equivalent to `type(x).__str__(x)`** because `str()` even avoids the normal attribute lookup procedure of the "function on the class". It only checks the [`tp_str`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_str) (or if that's NULL the [`tp_repr`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_repr)) slot of the class. So it doesn't even invoke `__getattribute__` of the metaclass, which `type(x).__str__(x)` would do:

```
class A(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print(name)
        if name == '__str__':
            return lambda self: 'A'
        else:
            return type.__getattribute__(self, name)

class B(metaclass=A):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'B'

>>> b = B()
>>> str(b)
'B'
>>> type(b).__str__(b)
__str__
'A'
```

However in the absense of a metaclass it *might* be helpful to think of `str(x)` as equivalent to `type(x).__str__(x)`. But while (potentially) helpful it's not correct.

Comment: Does this also apply to other built-in functions like that (e.g., next)? Can you point me to some docs that elaborate this?

Comment: Also, I guess what I should have really asked: Is there a way around this? So I don't have to call super(B, b).__str__()?

Comment: @tjanson Yes, several builtins bypass `__getattribute__` (see the note in the docs on [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)). However there's no complete list, it's just mentioned that it does that for "performance reasons".

Comment: @tjanson I don't know if there's a way around that. Probably but that won't be trivial because you have to monkey-patch the built-in `str` function or otherwise mess with the internals.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right. See `type.__str__()`

Comment: @tjanson  Regarding a way around it: there is a patch [here](https://bugs.python.org/file1027/abstract2.diff) (from Raymond Hettinger) which provides that.  But it never got merged, Guido declared it was better just to document that dunder methods must be called explicitly when working with a `super` instance.  See [issue805304](https://bugs.python.org/issue805304) for the back and forth.

Answer (score -1):

The docs are wrong.

`str(x)` is *actually* equivalent to `type(x).__str__(x)`.

If you `print(type(b_super).__str__(b_super))`, you get the obvious result.

(even this might be oversimplified in the case of weird metaclasses)

Comment: Sorry, but `str(x)` **is not** equivalent to `type(x).__str__(x)`. I updated my answer to reflect that (would've been too long for a comment).